# Add tellraw command function to signs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to make a map where the signs are empty but talk in chat when you right-click them, but it keeps showing red in the command block and giving the error: Expected '}' at position 135 llraw @p "<--[HERE], this is my code `/setblock ~ ~1 ~ oak_wall_sign[facing=south]{ Text1:"[{\"text\":\"\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"tellraw @p "Hello"\"}}]" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The information about requiring JSON input is incorrect, however my answer still uses it. The correct command would be:

```
/give @p minecraft:oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:'{"text":"Minecraft Tools","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"tellraw @a {\\"text\\": \\"Hello\\"}"}}'},display:{Name:'{"text":"Custom Sign"}'}}
```

which alternates single quotes and double quotes to avoid the nested quote problem

#### Original Answer

> `tellraw @p "Hello"`

Tellraw commands accept JSON as their input, not raw text. I'd recommend first testing this on its own:

```
/tellraw @p {"text": "hello"}
```

This probably won't work on the sign though, my guess is you'll need:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ oak_wall_sign[facing=south]{ Text1:"[{\"text\":\"\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"tellraw @p {\"text\": \"Hello\"}\"}}]" }
```

Or maybe even:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ oak_wall_sign[facing=south]{ Text1:"[{\"text\":\"\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"tellraw @p {\\"text\\": \\"Hello\\"}\"}}]" }
```

Note the double backslashes.

Comment: I tried using raw text alone (/tellraw @p "Hello") and it worked, but my main issue is that double quotes just break the command and the command block does nothing, your first solution actually spawned I sign but when I right-clicked it nothing happened. I am playing on 1.17.1 if that makes a difference, I just used your command with /say instead of tellraw, so the issue isn't format, but that brings in the first problem of the name popping up

Comment: In that case, I stand corrected. The issue seems to be with nested JSON quotes. Using a [sign generator](https://minecraft.tools/en/sign.php), I managed to get this, note that they use single quotes `'`: 
`/give @p minecraft:oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:'{"text":"Minecraft Tools","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"tellraw @a {\\"text\\": \\"Hello\\"}"}}'},display:{Name:'{"text":"Custom Sign"}'}}`